# How can I know hooked keyboard ID?

Tags: windows, keyboard, device

I have two keyboards connected on my computer. I want to use one for the main keyboard, and another for a specific application. For example, keyboard #1 is used for Windows, and keyboard #2 is used *only* in my application.

Is it possible? If yes, which language should I use? Do I need to access to the driver? I precise that I'm running under Windows...

Comment: I think you want RegisterRawInputDevice.

Comment: GetRawInputDeviceList seems to fit with my need. I'm able now to list all my HID devices. There is a code here: http://www.siteduzero.com/forum-83-716573-p1-api-win-raw-input.html (see the post of The_Real_Nox). Now, I'm trying to get raw data only from a specific device, and not a group of device, such as Keyboards. Any idea?

Comment: I've never used this API, but based on the documentation it looks as if you have to receive the raw input from all keyboards and then call DefRawInputProc to pass on the input from those keyboards you're not interested in.  If you do get this working, please post an answer (preferably including working code) for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a link that explain step by step how to intercept keyboard keys, and how to identify the device that sent the keystroke.

*[Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard)*

This example uses C# language.